# Laravel merge laravel collection attributes into one array / collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

Given a laravel collection of models and relations like so:

```
$usersAndBookings = [
  {
    id : 1,
    bookings : [
      { id : 1 },
      { id : 2 },
      { id : 3 },
    ]
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    bookings : [
      { id : 14 },
      { id : 15 },
    ]
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    bookings : [
      { id : 21 },
      { id : 22 },
      { id : 23 },
      { id : 24 },
    ]
  },
];
```

Is there a way to merge all `bookings`, to effectively get

```
$bookings = [
  { id : 1 },
  { id : 2 },
  { id : 3 },
  { id : 14 },
  { id : 15 },
  { id : 21 },
  { id : 22 },
  { id : 23 },
  { id : 24 },
];
```

I've tried:

```
$usersAndBookings->pluck('bookings');
```

This nearly works. It gives me:

```
$bookings = [
  [
    { id : 1 },
    { id : 2 },
    { id : 3 },
  ],
  [
    { id : 14 },
    { id : 15 },
  ],
  [
    { id : 21 },
    { id : 22 },
    { id : 23 },
    { id : 24 },
  ]
];
```

Is there a way to now merge those plucked values?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have it!

```
$bookings = $usersAndBookings->pluck('bookings')->collapse();;
```